# action is executed before the event occurs

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a button which when clicked must call a function in react. But the function runs whenever i reload the page before i click the button. And it doesn't work when i click the button.This is my code here:

```
show(){
  console.log('button Clicked');
}
render(){
  return(
    <button onClick={this.show()}>Show</button>
  )
}
```

The function show runs everytime i reload the page but not when i click the button.Shouldn't the function run after i click the button?Can you tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You passed a function call to it, which will get evaluated (executed). You need to provide it with a function instead:

`<button onClick={() => this.show()}>Show</button>`

You can use `this.show` too (without parenthesis) but might need to bind it or declare `show` as stage-3 class property if you are accessing `this` in `show`.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently executing the function immediately. For it to be called only when you click use the fat arrow in the `onClick` event:

```
render(){
  return(
    <button onClick={() => this.show()}>Show</button>
  )
}
```